# Google Apps Script "Service invoked too many times for one day"

Tags: google-apps-script

I am getting an error "Service invoked too many times for one day" while fetching the drafts using GmailApp.getDrafts().
The documentation says that we can read and write 20,000 emails per day and I am sure that I don't have 20,000 emails in my drafts but still I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

Even though your daily limit may be quite high, it's still possible to get service invoked too many times errors because they use a rate measurement so if you take the total quota and divide it by the number of seconds in a day then you get max operations per second.  Stay below that rate and my experience suggests you will not have any problems.

However, now that you've exceeded their limit you may have to wait a while but in my experience you won't have to wait the entire day.

I don't know if there are any references to confirm this behavior.